# Nginx wrong request interpretation

Tags: linux, nginx, openwrt

I got strange request received/interpreted by nginx.

What I'am doing...

**Sending request in shell:**

`$ echo -ne "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost\r\n\r\n" | nc localhost 80`

**Got log /var/log/nginx/access.log**:

`127.0.0.1 - - [23/Aug/2016:11:49:26 +0000] "@x\xEF\x01\xDCe\xCA\xB6t HTTP/1.1" "-" 400 172 "-" "-" "-"`

Somehow nginx interpreted `GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost\r\n\r\n` as `@x\xEF\x01\xDCe\xCA\xB6t HTTP/1.1`. Seems like it changes first several bytes.

**Env:**

- Openwrt, Linux-3.18
- nginx-1.4.7

**nginx.conf:**

```
user nobody nogroup;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    #default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]"$request" "$request_uri" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /www;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
```

}

**Strace:**

At the same time I can see in strace correct request `recv(3, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost\r"..., 1024, 0) = 35`.

So as a conclusion: something wrong with nginx or its configuration.

**Update**: Simple solution to start using the new version;)

Comment: Did you try another client, other than nc? For example, telnet. Does the server respond anything to you?

Comment: Yes of course, I tried telnet from local/remote client, curl, httpie. The same.

Comment: Maybe try a minimal nginx config? Also, try to run tcpdump to be sure that this is an nginx issue: `tcpdump -i lo -A port 80`

Comment: I have checked it with tcpdump. Everything looks Ok. And config that I use is pretty simple. I tried several options.

Comment: I just checked on my device with the same versions of OpenWrt and nginx, and default config - everything works fine: `127.0.0.1 - - [24/Aug/2016:14:14:02 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 168 "-" "-"`.Sorry, I can't think of anything else what could be wrong in your case.

Comment: Yeah, I know)) I have a little different build and it works fine. I built x86 tested build and it works fine also. It's extremely strange behavior. I think it's time to debug nginx with gdb))